# Error on creating a BPMN diagram with BPMN2 and Graphiti

Tags: eclipse, grails, jbpm, bpmn, graphiti

I'm trying to use `Drools Gorm` plugin to build process in my `Grails` application. Therefore, it is needed to use bpmn diagrams in order to instanciate a process. For this, i'm started to use two eclipse plugins: the `BPMN2` and `Graphiti` (that is required for the first one).

But, when i try to create a .bpmn file on `src/diagrams`, i'm getting this error on output alert screen:
Error `org/eclipse/graphiti/ui/editor/diagrameditorfactory`

I looked everywhere and i don't find any reasonable solutions. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the drools jBPM plugin? It seems to work pretty well. If you are alright with using another editor, you should try that. The update site is located [here](http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.Final/org.drools.updatesite/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I actually tried other plugins like Bizagi, Bonita, and jBPM. Analyzing these tools, my impressions was that jBPM is a very powerful engine and has more features.